# Get text following a keyword and stopping at new line in PHP

Tags: php, keyword

I have a document that a string that has a dynamic date but also contains other data I don't need. A typical string looks something like this

```
\n\n  \n     \n  Date: Jan. 25, 2012\n  \n  Location:\n     \n       \n         Ukraine,\n       \n
```

I wanted to grab the information between `Date:` and `\n` as the date shows up in the form above Month. Day, Year - but also as numeric values such as  `1.25.2012`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You need to use a regex (preg_match). Are your data normalized in a single format (Jan. 25, 2012 for example) or do you have different format to normalized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/Date: ([^\n]+)/', $line, $match)) {
    echo $match[1];
}
```

`$match[1]` will contain the date, which is any match after `Date:` that is not a newline. How to parse it from there, you'll have to decide.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more elegant way, but I have done something like that before:

```
<?php
$string="\n\n  \n     \n  Date:\n\n  \n     \n  Date: Jan. 25, 2012\n  \n  Location:\n     \n       \n         Ukraine,\n       \n \n  \n  Location:\n     \n       \n         Ukraine,\n       \n ";


list($trash,$keep)=explode('Data:',$string); 
//or 'Date: ' if you do not want that leading space.
list($keep,$trash)=explode("\n",$keep);

echo $keep;
// Jan. 25, 2012
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use explode and specify the delimiters.
and store it in an array.